# Understanding the hamming weight metric

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, coding-theory

## Definition: Hamming weight

Consider any $z\in\mathbb Z$. The hamming weight of $binary(z)$ is then defined as the hamming distance [1] to the zero string of same length. That means (using the language of coding-theory) every set bit increases the weight. Otherwise defined by linear algebra as: Let $z=\sum_{i=0}^n z_i 2^i$ then the hamming weight $h(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n z_i$.

This is the definition of Hamming weight, that I know.

## Question

How could it be, that then $u=-2^{77} +2^{50} + 2^{33}$ has $h(u)=3$ or $v=2^{35}-2^{32}-2^{18}+2^8+1$ has $h(v)=5$? The negative sign in the beginning is confusing me. That tells me, that I have to consider 3 conditions, instead of 2?

## Binary representation of u and v

$u=-0b11111111111111111111111111011111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000$

and

$v=0b11011111111111111000000000100000001$

That shows, that the given definition does not hold in case, the given hamming weight by [2] is right.

## References

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

[2] https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/334

Comment: I would think that the Hamming weight is defined only for non-negative integers. For negative integers it makes sense only when they are presented in 2s complement *with a fixed number of bits* (effectively narrowing down to a finite range such as $[-32768,32767]$). Anyway, the integer $m=2^n-1$ has weight $n$ because $m=111\ldots1_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The Hamming weight does not take the value of the coefficient into account, it simply adds $1$ if the coefficient is $\ne 0$ :

$$u=-2^{77} +2^{50} + 2^{33} \Rightarrow h(u) = 1+1+1 = 3$$

$$v=2^{35}-2^{32}-2^{18}+2^8+1 \Rightarrow h(v) = 1+1+1+1+1 = 5 $$

The general formula is :

$$z = \sum_{i=0}^n z_i2^i  \Rightarrow h(z) = \sum_{i=0\\z_i\ne 0}^n 1$$

Comment: This seems unlikely, as $2^3-2^0=2^2+2^1+2^0$ but the Hamming weights would be different.

Comment: Do you write $197$ as $10^2 + 9*10^1 + 7*10^0$ or $2*10^2-3*10^0$. ? The same rule apply when writing binary numbers.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But *you* are writing your number $v$ with negative signs in it, so what if you write that same number $v$ in binary with only positive coefficients?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was simply re-using the numbers the author provided. When you write a number in base $n$, you write each components of the powers of $n$ and then if you want a negative number you add a minus *before* the number.

$197$ means $1*10^2+9*10^1+7*10^0$. Indeed we have $197 = 200-3 = 2*10^2-3*10^0$ (and an infinity of other equalities involving powers of $10$) but we don't write something like $197=20(-3)$. This applies to binary numbers. The example the author gave is erronous, but if he has to apply $h()$ anyway, then my explanation is correct.

Comment: So the hamming weight is not uniquely defined? This is weird :( If h() depends on the chosen representation: $x:=_{(1)}2^n-1=_{(2)}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k$, then we have $h(x)=\begin{cases} 2 & if (1)\\ n & if (2)\end{cases}$.

Comment: If you can agree a number has a unique binary representation (which is the case) then the hamming weight of a given number **is** unique.

Comment: IMHO this is just wrong. To reiterate: $2^3-2^0=2^2+2^1+2^0$, so you must have $h(2^3-2^0)=h(2^2+2^1+2^0)$. Otherwise you don't have a function.